# How can I automatically start the JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder?

Tags: cucumber, jmeter, recorder

I am trying to automate the creation of JMeter scripts based on existing Cucumber tests to avoid maintaining two separate sets of tests (one for acceptance and one for load testing).

The Cucumber recording works great locally when I add the HTTP Recorder to the Workbench and start the recording, however I cannot figure out how I can automatically start it from the command line. Is this possible at all?

**Why not run Cucumber from JMeter?**
Because I'd like to avoid running multiple instances of Cucumber at the same time, and I'd like to be able to distribute the load generation (using jmeter-server)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible yet.

You should discuss this on [user mailing list](http://jmeter.apache.org/mail.html) to give more details on your request.

If this looks useful, then you would create an Enhancement request on [JMeter bugzilla](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) and feature may be developed.